# OCL - get value of variable

Tags: ocl, model-driven, model-driven-development

How can I get the value of variable instead of its name? The below code return "n" string which is the name of the variable. I need value of n.

```
s.targets.first().name.name
```

[The Metamodel](http://www.4shared.com/folder/-PZLAXRZ/Metamodel.html)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide us the model you are working on (model and metamodel if it is a special one).

Comment: @VincentAranega I am working on ETL metamodel. I edited my post and added it.